# Using the Qualify statement on an Interval data type to filter out positive and null values

Tags: teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to update a table to set the Dup_Flag column equal to 'Y' when the Dup1 value is negative.

I think I need to specify this condition on a Qualify clause but I don't know how to write it. Hoping to get some help here.

I am using Teradata SQL Assistant version 17.10.03.22

This is my code:

```
UPDATE Table1
FROM
(
    SELECT
    "Date",
    Call_GUID,
    DeDup_CID,
    Initial_Call_Time,
    Final_Call_Time,        
    (Initial_Call_Time) - MIN (Final_Call_Time) OVER (
    PARTITION BY DeDup_CID,
            "Date" 
    ORDER BY Initial_Call_Time ASC
        ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING 
        AND 1 PRECEDING) DAY(4) TO SECOND AS Dup1   
    FROM    Table1
QUALIFY Dup1 < 0 
)AS a
SET Dup_Flag = 'Y'
WHERE   Table1."Date" = a."Date"
    AND Table1.Call_GUID = a.Call_GUID
    AND Table1.Initial_Call_Time = a.Initial_Call_Time
    AND Table1.Final_Call_Time = a.Final_Call_Time
```

When I run this code, I get error message:  Failed 5407. Invalid operation for DateTime or Interval.

This is how the data that results from the nested 'select' statement looks like:

| Date | Call_GUID | DeDup_CID | Initial_Call_Time | Final_Call_Time | Dup1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09/21/2023 | 4B7FF52 | 2140000000 | 09/21/2023 08:01:17 | 09/21/2023 08:04:00 | ? |
| 09/21/2023 | A174742 | 2140000000 | 09/21/2023 08:03:33 | 09/21/2023 08:04:01 | -0 00:00:26.180000 |
| 09/21/2023 | C174756 | 2140000000 | 09/21/2023 08:18:28 | 09/21/2023 08:19:02 | 0 00:14:27.074000 |

This is what I am expecting to get from the 'qualify' statement:

| Date | Call_GUID | DeDup_CID | Initial_Call_Time | Final_Call_Time | Dup1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09/21/2023 | A174742 | 2140000000 | 09/21/2023 08:03:33 | 09/21/2023 08:04:01 | -0 00:00:26.180000 |

Comment: You can't compare an INTERVAL type with an INTEGER type. Use Dup1 < INTERVAL '0' SECOND

Comment: Thank you very much, @Fred.  That was it.